# Delphi TIdHTTP POST does not encode plus sign

Tags: delphi, http-post, delphi-2010, idhttp

I have a TIdHTTP component on a form, and I am sending an http POST request to a cloud-based server. Everything works brilliantly, except for 1 field: a text string with a plus sign, e.g. 'hello world+dog', is getting saved as 'hello world dog'.

Researching this problem, I realise that a '+' in a URL is regarded as a space, so one has to encode it. This is where I'm stumped; it looks like the rest of the POST request is encoded by the TIdHTTP component, except for the '+'.

Looking at the request through Fiddler, it's coming through as 'hello%20world+dog'. If I manually encode the '+' (hello world%2Bdog), the result is 'hello%20world%252Bdog'.

I really don't know what I'm doing here, so if someone could point me in the right direction it would be most appreciated.

Other information:

I am using Delphi 2010. The component doesn't have any special settings, I presume I might need to set something? The header content-type that comes through in Fiddler is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

Then, the Delphi code:

```
Request:='hello world+dog';
URL    :='http://............./ExecuteWithErrors';

TSL:=TStringList.Create;
TSL.Add('query='+Request);

Try
begin
  IdHTTP1.ConnectTimeout:=5000;
  IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout   :=5000;

  Reply:=IdHTTP1.Post(URL,TSL);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of Indy and need to upgrade.

`TIdHTTP`'s webform data encoder was changed several times in late 2010.  Your version appears to predate all of those changes.

In your version, `TIdHTTP` uses `TIdURI.ParamsEncode()` internally to encode the form data, where a space character is encoded as `%20` and a `+` character is left un-encoded, thus:

```
hello%20world+dog
```

In October 2010, the encoder was updated to encode a space character as `&` before calling `TIdURI.ParamsEncode()`, thus:

```
hello&world+dog
```

In early December 2010, the encoder was updated to encode a space character as `+` instead, thus:

```
hello+world+dog
```

In late December 2010, the encoder was *completely re-written* to follow W3C's HTML specifications for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  A space character is encoded as `+` and a `+` character is encoded as `%2B`, thus:

```
hello+world%2Bdog
```

In all cases, the above logic is applied only if the `hoForceEncodeParams` flag is enabled in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property (which it is by default).  If upgrading is not an option, you will have to disable the `hoForceEncodeParams` flag and manually encode the `TStringList` content yourself:

```
Request:='hello+world%2Bdog';
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed and very clear answer! For now, I disabled the hoForceEncodeParams flag, and encoded the string myself, this has worked like a charm. Stupid question: can one just update the indy component? I have never done this before, if that is what you mean. We are rewriting our software in Delphi XE so is not a major issue for us, but would be interested to know how that works.

Comment: [Indy 10 Installation Instructions](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.aspx)